# Restyling UWP Toolkit Expander Arrow

Tags: c#, uwp, resourcedictionary, windows-community-toolkit

I'm trying to restyle the Expander control from the Windows Community Toolkit, changing the default ">" symbol to a filled arrow (kind of like a Play button).  Following the accepted answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44851453/restyling-the-wpf-extended-toolkits-childwindow), I copied the default style from the Community Toolkit github repo, and pasted it into a ResourceDictionary (named CustomStyles.xaml), then changed the `FontIcon` `Glyph` property from `&#xE76C;` to `&#xE937;`.  I've referenced that ResourceDictionary in the `Page.Resources` section, and then bound the new style to the Expander's `HeaderTemplate` property with a `StaticResource` reference.  Everything should work, but something is causing it to fail.

The exception being thrown is of no help either, as the error displays the message `Failed to assign to property 'Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.HeaderedContentControl.HeaderTemplate'. The text associated with this error code could not be found.`

Can someone help with this please?

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page
x:Class="SharpFTP.MainPage"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
xmlns:local="using:SharpFTP"
xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
xmlns:toolkit="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"
mc:Ignorable="d"
Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
<Page.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="CustomStyles.xaml" />
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="3*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" MinHeight="40" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel x:Name="itemsPanel" Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0">
        <toolkit:Expander Header="Favorites" ExpandDirection="Down" HeaderTemplate="{StaticResource expanderFullArrowStyle}">

        </toolkit:Expander>
        <TextBlock Text="Favorites" />
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
            <TextBlock Text="Connected to " Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="LightGray" />
            <TextBlock Text="     10.3.12.128" Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" Foreground="White"/>
        </StackPanel>
        <AppBarSeparator Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=itemsPanel}" Height="2" Foreground="LightGray" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

**ResourceDictionary XAML**

I've included only the modified portion as the full style is 300 lines long.  The full default Expander style can be found [here](https://github.com/windows-toolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/Expander/Expander.xaml)

```
    <FontIcon x:Name="Arrow" Margin="12" FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets" FontSize="12"
              Glyph="&#xE937;" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
              <FontIcon.RenderTransform>
                      <RotateTransform />
              </FontIcon.RenderTransform>
    </FontIcon>
```

Answer (score 0):

The cause of your error should be a type mismatch.

You have modified the default style of Expender, then `expanderFullArrowStyle` should not be used on `HeaderTemplate`. Please try this:

```xml
<toolkit:Expander Header="Favorites" ExpandDirection="Down" Style="{StaticResource expanderFullArrowStyle}">
</toolkit:Expander>
```

Comment: This did lead me to a (partial) solution, although making that change didn't fix it:  The problem was with the TargetType in the ResourceDictionary.  I changed both TargetType instances to `toolkit:Expander`, and then the replacement style showed up.  Unfortunately, this broke the Expander so that it no longer shows a Header, rotates, or expands anymore.  I'm certain this is because it no longer functions as a ToggleButton, but if I leave either of the TargetTypes as a ToggleButton is crashes before Initializing.

Comment: What you are showing only seems to be the default style. Can you provide your modified style?